a general integral mod-inequality
We know that for any $\sigma$-finite measure space $(X,\mu)$, one has the following inequality $$\left|\int_Xf\,d\mu\right|\leq\int_X|f|\,d\mu$$ I just wonder whether the following inequality $$\left|\int_Xf\,d\mu\right|^p\leq\int_X|f|^p\,d\mu$$ would hold in more general sense for some particular choice of $p$ (or for all $p$). It is obvious that for $p=1$ this holds true. Any help is appreciated.

Do you think it holds for $f=1_E$?

In general, no. Simply picking $f=1$ and varying $\mu$ will yield a counterexample for any reasonable assumptions. One important case however, where it does work, assuming $p\geq 1$ is if $\mu$ is a probability measure. See Jensen's inequality.
